# Can I conclude my finding with just one linear regression result?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn Linear Regression and I'd like someone to look at my notebook to see if I miss out anything at all. How how else I can tune my model better.

Here's my notebook.

I get the dataset from here which is really simple.

http://college.cengage.com/mathematics/brase/understandable_statistics/7e/students/datasets/slr/frames/frame.html

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('slr12.csv', names=['annual', 'cost'], header=0)
df.describe()

df.plot(kind='scatter', x='X', y='Y');
```

[image]

```
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df['X'], df['Y'])

plt.plot(df['X'], df['Y'], 'o', label='Original data', markersize=2)
plt.plot(df['X'], slope*df['X'] + intercept, 'r', label='Fitted line')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

So from this trend we can predict that if you annual fee is high then you need your startup cost will be high as well.

Comment: I suggest taking a MOOC to learn a little about model tuning and assessment. Two options are Andrew Ng's ML Coursera course or the tutorials on Kaggle.  But this question is too green and vague to answer with anything other than a tutorial on the basics of ML.